# making virtual environment with venv in python

Tags: python-venv

I am building a data analysis pipeline in which I need to create a `virtual environment` using this command:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

And then I will activate it using:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

I have 2 questions:

1- would it be fine to call the `venv` also `venv`? In fact would it make problem if I have 2 venv in the same command?

2- in the manual page it is mentioned that after the activation of virtual environment, “you can confirm you’re in the virtual environment by checking the location of your Python interpreter” using this command:  “`which python` “. Does it have any advantage to add it to my pipeline?

Comment: Sure, you can call it `venv`. I don't see much benefit in calling the `which python` in the pipeline..

Comment: For a CI pipeline (or anything that is non-interactive, scripts, etc.) you might also want to skip the "activation" and instead directly call the executables that are in the virtual environment's `bin` directory, for example `path/to/venv/bin/python something.py` or `path/to/venv/bin/executable`.

Comment: @sinoroc what is the added value if I skip the activation step?

Comment: In general, in my own experience, I found that calling the executables from the virtual environment's `bin` directory always works reliably everywhere (when activating does not always work). -- Some pipelines execute each step independently, so if in one step you activate the Python virtual environment, in the next step it already is not active anymore.